# Edit Layout disappears

Tags: visualforce, detail, view

I have made a VisualForce page that is using apex:detail on my dev org. I then set the view for Campaigns to this VF page however now the "Edit Layout" button is gone from the Campaign page layout.

Is there a way to bring this link back?

Also will this occur if this was packaged and put on a production org as well or is it just a problem for dev orgs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No the edit layout link displays on the standard pages, you can still modify the layout by going into setup -> customize -> campaigns -> page layouts.

Comment: Right. While I am fine with this on my own dev org, I worry that this would be a pretty big thing to take away from those who use my package, especially on Campaigns.